# Why is my HTML generating table columns like this?

Tags: html, css

I am using HTML to generate a table to display something like this:

[image: Table HTML]

My HTML code snippet looks something like this:

[image: HTML Code]

As you can see QTR 6, 7, 8 have huge space problems compared to other and i don't know why it's behaving like this even though the `colspan` for all is same i.e. `1`.

Anybody have any idea why it is behaving like this?

Comment: Please share your code. Can't see anything

Comment: @CharuMaheshwari Sorry,couldn't post it properly the first time

Comment: @CharuMaheshwari Still no answer? is it  the question? it's not full enough?

Comment: Try using `display: inline-block`.

Comment: @user7393973 doesn't work

Comment: You should edit your question with more or all of the code so it is easier to understand why and how to fix it.

Comment: @user7393973 well,the code is huge,i can't post all of it here.i am displaying tables inside a table ,so is there a way to make this table independent of those styles?

Comment: Can you at least show all of the CSS styles being applied/inherit (use DevTools on Chrome)

Comment: @AnaPliskova I have created a fiddle with the information you have mentioned above. https://jsfiddle.net/a120jzpg/10/ But I am not able to replicate the issue which you are facing. I suggest you to add your exact code in the fiddle, it would be easy to help.

Comment: If you have nested tables, and you want to avoid styles being applied differently then check https://jsfiddle.net/a120jzpg/22/  fiddle

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have the same width for each columns you can set:

```
table {
  table-layout: fixed;
  width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: @AnaPliskova can you provide a live example through jsfiddle (or any other website) ? So we can see all the code involved